# History of infinte cartesian products in set theory

Tags: notation, set-theory, math-history

> **Question.** On what date was the notation $\prod_{i \in I}X_i$ first used in a published article, where the $X_i$ denote sets, the index set $I$ is infinite, and it's not the case that the author assumes that all of the $X_i$'s denote the same set?

Comment: Do you mean the actual use of the $\prod$ symbol, or anything that might have been previously used, such as a large $\times$ symbol?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I've thought about your question a bit, and I think I'm specifically looking for the $\prod$ notation. And it shouldn't just be $\prod_{i = 0}^\infty,$ but rather $\prod_{i \in I}$. My reasoning being that since, dependent products generalize exponential objects (as in:  $Y^X = \prod_{x \in X} Y$). Thus this notation is imo a pretty important milestone in the history of modern math. I'm also interested in the tagged union notation $\sum_{i \in I}$ and/or $\coprod_{i \in I}$ for similar reasons.

Comment: One place definitely worth looking into are the older volumes of [**Fundamenta Mathematicae**](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-journal-fm) (maybe start in the early 1930s, especially papers by Sierpinski, Szpilrajn, Hausdorff, Tarski, Kuratowski, Birkhoff, Nobeling ... heck, pretty much anyone) and the earliest few volumes of [**Colloquium Mathematicum**](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-journal-cm?q=bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-publisher-institute_of_mathematics_polish_academy_of_sciences;2&qt=CHILDREN-STATELESS).

Comment: Also, flip through the collected papers of those who used products of sets in a lot of their papers, such as [Sierpinski](https://www.worldcat.org/title/uvres-choisies/oclc/3052083) and [Mazurkiewicz](https://www.worldcat.org/title/travaux-de-topologie-et-ses-applications/oclc/321315) and [Marczewski](https://www.worldcat.org/title/collected-mathematical-papers/oclc/36008876) and other such people. The papers are usually arranged chronologically. However, keep in mind that older authors during a period of notation change typically hold onto the older notation longer than others.